# How Handle Any Type of Data in Codable Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, codable

I have gone through many articles but still could not find a best approach to tackle this situation . I am having different models , that are used to be returned on the basis of type of cell . What is the best approach to handle with Any data type (Any consists of more than three different data models ). See my code below

```
import Foundation


struct OverviewWorkout : Decodable {
    
    enum WorkoutType: String, Codable {
        case workout
        case coach
        case bodyArea
        case challenge
        case title
        case group
        case trainer
    }

    var type: WorkoutType
    var data : Any

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try container.decode(WorkoutType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .workout, .challenge:
            data = try container.decode(Workout.self, forKey: .data)
        case .coach:
            data = try container.decode(CoachInstruction.self, forKey: .data)
        case .bodyArea:
            data = try container.decode([Workout].self, forKey: .data)
        case .title:
            data = try container.decode(Title.self, forKey: .data)

        case .group:
            data = try container.decode([Workout].self, forKey: .data)
      // trainer data
        case .trainer:
            data = try container.decode([Trainer].self, forKey: .data)

        }
       
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case type,data
        
    }
}

extension OverviewWorkout {
    struct Title: Codable {
        let title: String
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `Any`, use a enum with associated value.

Comment: can you please explain your answer a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the Type enum with associated values as defined below:

```swift
   struct OverviewWorkout : Decodable {

      var type: WorkoutType 

      enum WorkoutType: String, Codable {
        case workout(data: Workout)
        case coach(data: CoachInstruction)
        case bodyArea(data: [Workout])
        case title(data: Title)
        case group(data: [Workout])
        case trainer(data: Trainer)
    }

   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        type = try container.decode(WorkoutType.self, forKey: .type)
        switch type {
        case .workout:
            let data = try container.decode(Workout.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .workout(data: data)
        case .trainer:
            let data = try container.decode(Trainer.self, forKey: .data)
            self = .trainer(data: data)
        .
        .
        .

        }
       
    }
 }
```

I was short of time so couldn't compile it but I hope you this will give you an idea. Additionally, Sharing a reference article for you. [:D You might have visited already]

Comment: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0295-codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values.md 
Referece

Comment: Thanks for the quick response , That seems to be working now but the another issue I found , that is the encoding part is working perfectly fine but when I decode it says the key "type" is not found . What could be the cause of this issue? any suggestion

Comment: make the type key optional then. It surely means that the either the keyname is different in the json or its not present there for some object. If you think otherwise please share the json response here for which you are getting this error.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mentiion , but i have fixed the issue by encoding key as well. that is what i was missing. well it was quite helpul thanks alot.

Comment: Great, if it helped you, can you upvote the answer please.